# How to check if a 3 leveled nested list is a subset of another 3 leveled nested list

Tags: python, list, comparison-operators

I have 2 lists as `list<list<list>>` lists where I want to check if one of them is a subset of the other.

```
list_1 = [
           [
             [1,2],[2,3]
           ],
           [
             [3,4],[5,6]
           ]
         ]
list_2 = [
           [
             [3,4], [5, 6]
           ]
         ]
```

So expected output is that as list2 has [[[3,4]]] which is a part of list_1 so it should be a subset.

list_1 has 2 elements and its second element matches the first element in list_2 so list_2 is a subset of list_1.

The comparison is not at the element level but at list level.

I tried `set(list_2) < set(list_1)` but results in `unhashable type: list`. How can I achieve the above comparison then?

Comment: use the all() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check that `all` sublist in `list_2` are within `list_1`:

```
all(x in list_1 for x in list_2)
True
```

Here you have the [live example](https://repl.it/repls/ThoroughUntrueOpenlook)